# How to inject arguments in a dynamic property @Value

Tags: java, arrays, spring

I have a problem where I am trying to read a property from a resource property file and inject arguments via Java code.

I am using the @Value annotation from Spring.

Like the example below, let's say I have a property called person.description in a properties file, and I want to inject the first name as a parameter.

```
#Properties file
person.description = {0} studies at the University of Johannesburg.
```

Below is the method (Java) where the property is being called.

```
public String doSomething(@Value("${person.description}") String description, String studentName) {...
```

I expect the output to be the following:

John studies at the University of Johannesburg.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Hi @BohdanPetrenko, I am trying to inject the studentName as an argument. This is not working. The doSomething method is returning: 

{0} studies at the University of Johannesburg.

Not sure if you understand me correct.

Comment: Please provide us with full listing of  code of `doSomething` method. Probably [MessageFormat](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/98au/java/jdk1.2beta4/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) is what you are looking for

Comment: I may not understand what you are trying to do, if you want to obtain the person.description value. ¿by request or by context? if it's by context you need to do another thing. Like this

person.description = {0} studies at the University of Johannesburg.

Answer (score 0):

as in your properties, `person.description = {0} studies at the University of Johannesburg.`, then if you return this string it means that the value is being injected correctly.
Then for me it is normal that your function return this.
If you want to return with the name of the student, maybe `return description.replace('{0}', studentName);` or something like this would work ?